# CMake include directory not being added

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I'm on **OSX** and have the following **CMakeLists.txt file**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

project (Test)

add_executable (test main.cpp)

install (TARGETS test DESTINATION bin)

target_include_directories (test PRIVATE Source)
```

I get the **error**:

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (add_executable): main.cpp not found`

when running the makefile from the directory above `Source`.

I'm new to CMake so I've likely just made a noob mistake but I can't fix the error on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target_include_directories` is only going to add directories where your build system should search for include files, not source.

You can use `add_subdirectory` to add directories where source files live.

See documentation on [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) and [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_subdirectory.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add just `Source/main.cpp` then use

```
add_executable (test Source/main.cpp)
```

The target_include_directories or include_directories (that is for legacy versions of CMake) are telling to CMake where the .h files are.